# Template error: Unable to get mapping for AWSAMIRegionMap::us-gov-west-1::US1604HVM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mapping, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch tableau on AWS Gov-Cloud but I keep getting this mapping error, whether it is on us-gov-east or us-gov-west it throws this error at me I have the following condition set for gov-cloud in my `VPC-Template`

```
"GovCloudCondition": {
            "Fn::Equals": [
                {
                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "us-gov-west"
            ]
        }
```

as provided by AWS, I have a feeling the error resides there but I may be wrong. When I run this through CloudFormation I get the following error:

`Template error: Unable to get mapping for AWSAMIRegionMap::us-gov-west-1::US1604HVM`

I've tried searching for answers online and it really almost seems like this hasn't been attempted (I'm sure it has) before because I cannot find a gov-cloud related response

Comment: The error is related to a `Mapping` section in the template. Can you add that section to your Question, or point us to where you obtained the template so we can see its contents?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm gonna post a hasten of the entire thing there is only one reference to the word 'map' in the whole thing and I don't think it's that

Comment: @JohnRotenstein https://hastebin.com/evozokinus.json

Comment: @JohnRotenstein https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-aws-vpc/blob/master/templates/aws-vpc.template <-- this is where I got the template from

Comment: That template does not reference Tableau, nor does it including a mapping or a reference to `US1604HVM`. Therefore, I can't see how the template gave you this error. How are you launching the template? (By the way, `us-gov-west` is an invalid region name. It should be `us-gov-west-1`.)

Comment: Like I said there is no reference to mapping anywhere and it actually is at us-gov-west-1 in my s3 bucket I think I accidentally backspaced it at some point locally

Comment: Also counter check your mappings and where they are being reference to ensure that  spellings for the mappings match those in reference section.